# How can I determine the true result of Folder.CopyHere?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I'm copying a folder using `Folder.CopyHere`, and this method returns `S_OK`  even when the user aborts the process.

Is there any way at all of finding out if the user aborted?

Comment: That's only useful for scripting languages, use the [SHFileOperation() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.  Give you access to the  SHFILEOPSTRUCT.fAnyOperationsAborted member.

Comment: That's good to know, however I'm forced to use the `CopyHere` method for extracting ZIP archives among other things, and `SHFileOperation` doesn't seem to be able to do that.

Comment: [IFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx) can operate on non-filesystem items (such as ZIP archives, as long as you do not interpret the archive itself as a leaf node, but rather enumerate its children).

Comment: Using CopyHere to extract files from a zip is not supported for programmatic use.

Comment: @RaymondChen Can you please elaborate on this a bit, and what it means with regards to extracting zips on both Windows XP and the more modern versions? It would be good to have a definitive answer from you people at Microsoft.

Comment: The Windows shell does not have a zip extraction API.

Comment: @RaymondChen So even if we _can_ extract zips using the above methods, they are just unintended side-effects? It's such a vital function, and since Windows does know how to do it, it strikes me as odd that there's no native API for it.

Comment: System.IO.Compression contains APIs for manipulating zip files.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Marc Miller seems to disagree with your assessment ([PIDL Me This: The Explorer Storage Architecture](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcmill/archive/2005/10/06/478067.aspx)). It's a blog entry, so neither formal documentation nor contractual. The statement that *"you can use the shell's namespace object model as a sort of native API for enumerating and extracting ZIP file content"* seems to be rather explicit, though. Since the MSDN does not exclude ZIP archives from the shell API, and extracting/enumerating contents works, I'm going to have to guess that that's no coincidence.

Comment: Note the weasel words "sort of".

Comment: @RaymondChen: How can you make the call to `CopyHere` asynchronous? I have a bug because I am trying to pick a zip file being written at the moment by `CopyHere`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer seems to be that it's not possible to get the true result from `Folder.CopyHere`, and the solution is to instead use the `IFileOperation` interface, as suggested by IInspectable.